# How to read .rds R files with spatial data in python

Tags: python, r, r-sf

I used R to save a data set in `.rds` format. The problem is that I need to read this `.rds` file using Python without having R locally installed. This `.rds` file carries an object of class `sf data.framte`. A sample `.rds` can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tPnQnBPfRx4IFzgE2NwLkm_jtc_IZmGO).

I managed to use `rpy2` to open it. However, this library uses R to open the file. Since I am building a Python application, I don't want a R dependency.

Below, you can find a working solution using `rpy2`.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri
numpy2ri.activate()

from shapely.geometry import LineString

def rds_to_pandas(path='temp.rds'):

    readRDS = robjects.r['readRDS']
    df = readRDS('temp.rds')

    return df

def from_rvector_to_rlist(vector):

    return [list(v) for v in vector]

def from_rlist_to_coorlist(rlist):

    coorlist = []
    for r in rlist:
        bound = int(len(r)/2)
        coorlist.append(list(zip(r[:bound], r[bound:])))

    return coorlist[0]

# Open as GeoPandas
df = pd.DataFrame(rds_to_pandas())
df['geometry'] = df['geometry'].apply(from_rvector_to_rlist)
df['geometry'] = df['geometry'].apply(from_rlist_to_coorlist)
df['geometry'] = df['geometry'].apply(LineString)
```

When I try `pyreadr` I keep getting the same error:

`"ValueError: Unable to read from file"`

Does anyone know how to do open this `.rds` file either using `pyreadr` or a different method that does not have a R dependency?

Comment: I think you would need to save the rds as a feather file which is readable by both python and R.  However, I'm not sure if feather supports shapefile like columns.

Comment: @BenG. Unfortunately, Feather is not compatible with `sf` objects in R. When I try to save the spatial data using Feather, I get this error message. `>Error in writeFeather(x, path) : Not implemented: geometry is a list`

Comment: I  think you would have to save it as another file from R like geojson, then you could read it in through geopandas. I don't think it's possible to read an rds that has spatial data with python.